# Win32 LoadImage() from File Error

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, error-handling, bmp

Sorry if this is duplicate but I can't find answer elsewhere. I am simply trying to load an image during runtime using the LoadImage() function of WINAPI. I receive the error code(8) which indicates that there is not enough storage space(error codes found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

the file is relatively small(2.5kb) so I wonder if there is problem with my code:

```
void OnCreate()
{
...
HBITMAP hbmDeck = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance, L"standard.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION | LR_LOADFROMFILE);

    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    HBITMAP hbmT = SelectBitmap(hdc, hbmDeck);
    if(!hbmT)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to LoadImage - 'hbmDeck'", L"OnCreate()", MB_OK);
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, NULL, NULL);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Following [Gunner's correct advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10661197/366904), your code works just fine for me. I can't get it to break or reproduce the error you describe, even trying to load a 25 MB bitmap file. And I haven't done anything nutty like increasing the resource heap size. This is a standard installation of Windows 7 in a clean scratch Win32 project created by the VS 2010 wizard. Can you repro this in a similar clean project?

Comment: You should also just test the return value of LoadImage and ONLY if it is 0 should you call GetLastError.  If there was no error, then the API might not have called SetLastError, so that error code of 8 might of come from some other API call earlier in the call chain.

Comment: Can you load your bmp file into Paint? Maybe it's corrupted and says that it is a billion pixels tall. That would explain the "out of memory" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, some of the API return error codes are a bit cryptic and don't fit the error.

The file you are trying to load "standard.bmp" is a file on the disk NOT in the resource section right?   Well to load a file from the disk, the fist parameter of LoadImage (hInst) has to be NULL and the fuLoad flag needs to include LR_LOADFROMFILE which you correctly have.

Comment: I changed the first parameter of LoadImage() to NULL, I receive the same error

Comment: also, I used regedit to increase resource heap size(as suggested in a different thread) to no avail

Comment: @P.Avery: is your working folder (`GetCurrentDirectory`) matching the one in which you expect that `.bmp` file?